# Deleting a video from youtube YouTube Data API v3 and python

Tags: python-2.7, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm developing an application using Django and angularJS.
One of the major thing that worker server (coded in python, flask) does is downloading videos from s3 (which are uploaded by users) and uploading the videos to youtube.

Is there way to ***"delete a youtube video in python"***?.

There is no such a code example written in python.
Does anyone know how to do this simply, like the code example below?

This is sample code for uploading video. I referred this code and implemented uploading feature.

```
def get_authenticated_service(args):
  flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE,
    scope=YOUTUBE_UPLOAD_SCOPE,
    message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)

  storage = Storage("%s-oauth2.json" % sys.argv[0])
  credentials = storage.get()

  if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, args)

  return build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
    http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))

def initialize_upload(youtube, options):
  tags = None
  if options.keywords:
    tags = options.keywords.split(",")

  body=dict(
    snippet=dict(
      title=options.title,
      description=options.description,
      tags=tags,
      categoryId=options.category
    ),
    status=dict(
      privacyStatus=options.privacyStatus
    )
  )

  # Call the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
  insert_request = youtube.videos().insert(
    part=",".join(body.keys()),
    body=body,
    media_body=MediaFileUpload(options.file, chunksize=-1, resumable=True)
  )

  resumable_upload(insert_request)
```

Comment: Its part of the api I don't see why it wouldn't be part of the python client library if you are using that https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/delete

Comment: https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/youtube/v3/python/latest/youtube_v3.videos.html#delete

Answer (score 3):

Make a file called: delete_video.py

Usage: python delete_video.py --id=MY_VID_ID

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import httplib
import httplib2
import os
import random
import sys
import time

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import argparser, run_flow


# Explicitly tell the underlying HTTP transport library not to retry, since
# we are handling retry logic ourselves.
httplib2.RETRIES = 1

# Maximum number of times to retry before giving up.
MAX_RETRIES = 10

# Always retry when these exceptions are raised.
RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS = (httplib2.HttpLib2Error, IOError, httplib.NotConnected,
  httplib.IncompleteRead, httplib.ImproperConnectionState,
  httplib.CannotSendRequest, httplib.CannotSendHeader,
  httplib.ResponseNotReady, httplib.BadStatusLine)

# Always retry when an apiclient.errors.HttpError with one of these status
# codes is raised.
RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES = [500, 502, 503, 504]

# The CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE variable specifies the name of a file that contains
# the OAuth 2.0 information for this application, including its client_id and
# client_secret. You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from
# the Google Developers Console at
# https://console.developers.google.com/.
# Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
# For more information about using OAuth2 to access the YouTube Data API, see:
#   https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication
# For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, see:
#   https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secrets.json"

# This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
# authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
YOUTUBE_DELETE_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

# This variable defines a message to display if the CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE is
# missing.
MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = """
WARNING: Please configure OAuth 2.0

To make this sample run you will need to populate the client_secrets.json file
found at:

   %s

with information from the Developers Console
https://console.developers.google.com/

For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, please visit:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
""" % os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                                   CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE))

VALID_PRIVACY_STATUSES = ("public", "private", "unlisted")


def get_authenticated_service(args):
  flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE,
    scope=YOUTUBE_DELETE_SCOPE,
    message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)

  storage = Storage("%s-oauth2.json" % sys.argv[0])
  credentials = storage.get()

  if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, args)

  return build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
    http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    argparser.add_argument("--id", required=True, help="Video youtube ID")  
    args = argparser.parse_args()

    if not args.id:
        exit("Please specify a youtube ID using the --id= parameter.")

    youtube = get_authenticated_service(args)

    try:
        resp = youtube.videos().delete(id=args.id, onBehalfOfContentOwner=None).execute()

    except HttpError, e:
        print "An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status, e.content)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, was useful in a pinch. Only thing is to remember to install the [API Library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/) and set up the client_secrets.json file which will need an app engine project.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using the python client library I found this in the [documentation](https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/youtube/v3/python/latest/).

> [delete(id=*, onBehalfOfContentOwner=None)](https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/youtube/v3/python/latest/youtube_v3.videos.html#delete) Deletes a YouTube video.
>
> Args:   id: string, The id parameter specifies the YouTube video ID
>   for the resource that is being deleted. In a video resource, the id
>   property specifies the video's ID. (required)
>   onBehalfOfContentOwner: string, Note: This parameter is intended
>   exclusively for YouTube content partners.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figured out how to do that with your help